# Changing background color of specific coordinates

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, adminlte

I am using fullcalendar 
this is my code:

```
<div id="calendarTrash" class="calendar-trash">
                <img style="width: 50px; margin-left: 40%; display:none" id="trash-img"
                     src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/email-2-2/32/Trash-Email-Bin-512.png" />
            </div>
            <div id="calendar"></div>
```

and this is the script:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
eventDragStop: function (event, jsEvent) 
{
    var trashEl = jQuery('#trash-img');
    var ofs = trashEl.offset();
    var x1 = ofs.left;
    var x2 = ofs.left + trashEl.outerWidth(true);
    var y1 = ofs.top;
    var y2 = ofs.top + trashEl.outerHeight(true);
    if (jsEvent.pageX >= x1 && jsEvent.pageX <= x2 &&
        jsEvent.pageY >= y1 && jsEvent.pageY <= y2) 
    {
        deletefromDb(event);
    }
    $('#trash-img').css('display', 'none');
}, 
});
```

So I want to change the color of the div "#trash-img" as long as the event is in the coordinates of the "#trash-img" div....
can anyone help me please ?